# Using class instance variable for mutex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, synchronization, jruby, mutex

**Note:** The code summary shown below is *not* a distillation of the code that I had the problem with. I've left this original summary here since someone else already answered, but the *actual* code is shown in the answer I've provided below.

I haven't been able to isolate this to a small failing test case, but I'm getting a failure with the following general construct:

```
class Foo

  @mutex = Mutex.new

  ....

  def self.bar
    @mutex.synchronize { ... }
  end

end
```

If I create multiple threads invoking `Foo.bar`, sometimes `@mutex` will evaluate to `nil` in `bar`. If I use a constant (e.g. MUTEX) instead of an instance variable, I don't have this problem.

I don't know if it's significant, but I'm running on JRuby on a multi-core machine.

I'd appreciate any explanation or help in how to isolate the problem.

Update: I believe this is related to autoloading. With Rails, I was able to reproduce a similar problem with the following contents of `foo.rb` in one of the directories Rails autoloads from:

```
class Foo
  @mutex = Mutex.new
  def self.bar
    @mutex.synchronize {}
  end
end
```

When I then execute the following in the Rails console:

```
1.upto(4).map { Thread.new { Foo.bar }}.map(&:join)
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Foo
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.10@javlats/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:461:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.10@javlats/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1:in `evaluate'
```

and this behavior is the same in CRuby (MRI Ruby).

Answer (score 8):

Does it happen with a class variable? `@@mutex`. There might be a race condition with making new class-instances between threads and the new copy of `@mutex` isn't ready yet. Constants and class variables however, are shared between copies of the class and subclasses. Also, what if you put the `@mutex` init code in a memoized method such as:

```
def self.mutex
  @mutex ||= Mutex.new
end
```

Comment: I tried your two alternatives and the problem didn't occur with either of them, but your phrase "copy of @mutex" is worrisome, because unless all threads share the same mutex, the mutex isn't doing anything. :-)

Comment: I just mean it has to reinstantiate it when the new thread inits since its a class **instance** variable. Whereas the constant or class variable approach is shared. And the memoized method approach checks for a nil first and then inits.

Comment: I don't understand why it would need to be reinstantiated. Are you saying that each thread has it's own instance of the class?

Comment: Just ran a test under ruby 2.0, correction, they all have the same instance, but i can't recreate your problem. I ran this test, they don't come out nil and they all have the same object_ids: https://gist.github.com/DiegoSalazar/8961861

Answer (score 0):

While autoloading is indeed not thread safe in Rails like it is in Ruby 1.9 (per [Is autoload thread-safe in Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837912/is-autoload-thread-safe-in-ruby-1-9/6555010#6555010)), the problem I encountered was not due to that problem and the code I had was not an instance of the code I showed above, but rather an instance of the following:

```
class Foo
  @mutex = Mutex.new
  def self.bar
     @mutex.synchronize { }
  end
end

class Foobar < Foo ; end

Foobar.bar
```

The problem is that when executing method from a superclass, the value of `self` remains unchanged, so the value of `@mutex` within `Foo.bar` is interpreted in the context of the `Foobar` object, not the value of the `Foo` object.

This problem can be avoided by using a class variable (e.g. `@@mutex`) for the mutex.